# Ignore "Attribute.Min[]" validation if date is not changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation

I have two pages, one is where user can `create employee details`, another is where user can `update details of employee particular`.

There are several text fields like `name`, `age`, `work start date`.

This `work start date` will determine when the employee will start work.

On page load method in cs file, I set `tbWorkStartDate.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`. Thus, whenever the user goes into the page, the text field will be validated to prevent past date selection.

In one scenario, a user create an employee detail with start date of `29/05/2016`. Then on the date of `05/10/2016`, the user goes into the page and only update `name` and click `Save`, the system does not allow the user to `save`. This is because the validation on the date text field.

Is there a way to skip the validation error if the date is not changed at all?

I am currently using C#.

Comment: Is choosing the current day legal? Why not set the minimum date as the day before?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman Yes choosing current date is legal. The day before as in the day before current day?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the minimum value as such:

```
tbDateTest.Attributes["min"] = (DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Now the user may choose to keep the current date and it will be legal or instead pick a later date.

Comment: @Alvin So there are two forms? One for updating and one for entering the date? If so then only the create form should have this validation. On the update page this attribute should be impossible to change or perhaps only optional.

Comment: Yes, there are two forms. Hmm, that's what I thought so too. Thank you for your help anyway!